# What is the difference between Enable OpenGL with full KMS, enable OpenGL with fake KMS and Legacy in raspberry pi setting

Tags: opengl, raspberry-pi

I would like to know what is the difference between enabling OpenGL with different mode and how are they affecting the GPU usage.